# How can I put total in the title highchart

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I want to put this.total in the text of the title in center of pie chart. My code in: http://jsfiddle.net/Cp73s/2124/

```
title: {
            text: 'I want to put this.total here',
            align: 'center',
            verticalAlign: 'middle'
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate title

```
var total = 0
for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
    total += data[i][1]
}
```

Add

```
title: {
   text: total+'<br>AVISOS',
},
```

**Centre title in pie chart**
Refer to answer in [How to center chart title position dynamically inside pie chart in highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27840496/1608670)

Comment: Thx, but I want to change dynamic title. If I press in the legend to diabled some field, I want to change the total in the title.

Comment: Check out `legendItemClick` in http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.point.events

Answer (score 1):

Set `title.x`: http://jsfiddle.net/Cp73s/2127/

Text is positioned relative to the chart, not to the pie, so since you have legend on the right side, you need to add extra space for `x`. Of course, since your legend title can vary it will be a good idea to set fixed width for `legendItem`.

Comment: How can I modified the title?. I want to put total in title

Comment: You need to calculate title value before rendering chart. Then when you change some value on the chart (e.g. using legend) use [`chart.setTitle()`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.setTitle).