# Highcharts donut responsive text in center

Tags: javascript, highcharts, donut-chart

I have been searing for a solution to have centered text in highcharts donut. Some solutions use title, or subtitle with following option to center text but this does not work when chart is responsive and does not have specified width:

```
verticalAlign: 'middle',
floating: true
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pDdcd/483/

Does anybody have a solution which works when chart is responsive, even is it includes modified source code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to center chart title position dynamically inside pie chart in highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835768/how-to-center-chart-title-position-dynamically-inside-pie-chart-in-highcharts)

Comment: use `fontSize: this.chartWidth*0.05` to make text responsive. http://jsfiddle.net/d959tbwm/